# Why isn't an image from the local domain shown with the explanation that, for security reasons, only images from the local domain are allowed?

Tags: nodes, media, 9

I'm running Drupal Core 9.3.7, with basically the default set up. The Basic HTML editor is CKEditor. If I include an image in a page, that image is not shown when I view the page; on inspection, it is actually there, but with the `height="16" width="16"` attributes, and a title that says:

> This image has been removed. For security reasons, only images from the local domain are allowed

The image **is** in the local domain (the relative path is */files/inline-images/Picture%201.png*); it was literally uploaded in the content editor. If I put in the URL of the image into the browser, it works. It doesn't seem an upload or a permission issue.

If I go to *Configuration » Text formats and editors » Basic HTML » Configure* and deselect *Restrict images to this site*, the images appear.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm a complete Drupal newbie.

Comment: Is there a query string on the image URL?

Comment: @cliefen - no, just the URL to the file.

Comment: Does the text format have other filters active that might interfere here? I just read on https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_responsive_images/issues/2875845 (rather old though and for D8) that the "Display responsive images" and "Track images uploaded via a Text Editor" might have an effect on this.

Comment: @berliner There are a few other (default) ones on (Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML, align images, caption images, Track images uploaded via a Text Editor) but turning this off does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by re-ordering the filters, so tracking is done before the Restriction check.

- Track images uploaded via a Text Editor
- Restrict images to this site*
- Image Resize Filter: Resize images based on their given height and
  width attributes